# How does the choke on my mower work?

Tags: carburetor, small-engine

I am wondering if the choke may be part of the reason I am having [trouble with my mower](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/20930/small-engine-starts-then-stops). It appears that there is very little force causing it to stay open or closed. I am wondering if there is a spring that should be holding it one way or another, or if is vacuum operated.  What could be the mechanism for actuating this thing?

Comment: Does your small engine have a primer bulb?

Comment: There is typically a spring attached to the choke.  Look online for a manual or parts diagram.  A google image search might help also.

Comment: Can you provide the make/model/year of your mower?